# SP Online - custom Display Template - square boxes instead of font icons from Office UI Fabric icon set displayed in checked-in state

Tags: css, display-template, office-ui-fabric

I encountered a problem, that it displays only empty square boxes instead of nice (custom font) images from generated Office UI Fabric icons set, since I change the state of the with the web-part to checked-in state.

I have checked in google chrome developer tools,that the style inside icons-likes-inline.css is presented there (including the @font-face element), but it shows the square box(es)! 
And since I checked out the page and leave the edit mode I can see the icons again...  ??

in detail:
the css is added through custom  Item_DisplayTemplate (I have tried to do it also in paired Control_DisplayTemplate.html)

```
 $includeCSS(this.url, "~sitecollection/Style Library/MyCustomFeature/fabric-icons-likes-inline.css");
```

(the icons-likes-inline.css is published, also the Item_DisplayTemplate.html is e.g. in published/ or just in checked-in states)

The picture below shows the several screen shots from the chrome developer tools grabbed in time it was ok - and then comparing it in page checked-in state the developer tool produces the exactly the same results in all) ??

[image: sp online custom font square box troubles]

(Also didn't work in IE.)
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Using of non-inline variant has helped.

```
$includeCSS(this.url, "~sitecollection/Style Library/MyCustomFeature/fabric-icons-likes.css");
```

I don't know why exactly it works. It could be, that the (asynchronous) fetching the font data helped. Then it could mean, that $includeCSS does not work with the custom inline fonts perfectly well - the CSS part might not well prepared at moment of AddPostRenderCallback when trying to update the page DOM structure.